# Need help for SQL QUERY. Merging items using outer joins or union

Tags: php, mysql

```
[TABLE 1]
+---------+---------+------------------+
| post_id | user_id | description      |
+---------+---------+------------------+
|  1      | 1       | Sample post 1    |
|  2      | 1       | Sample post 2    |
|  3      | 2       | Sample post 3    |
|  4      | 2       | Sample post 4    |
|  5      | 3       | Sample post 5    |
+---------+---------+------------------+

[TABLE 2]
+---------+---------+---------+
| id      | user_id | post_id |
+---------+---------+---------+
|  1      | 1       |  1      |
|  2      | 2       |  2      |
+---------+---------+---------+
```

When the USER_ID 1 in TABLE 1 already existed in TABLE 2 with its respected POST_ID, it should not be part of return select query. Instead, it would return POST_ID 2,3,4,5 in TABLE 1.

When the USER_ID 2 in TABLE 1 already existed in TABLE 2 with its respected POST_ID, the expected return select query would be POST_ID 1,3,4,5 in TABLE 1 as well as the other id's.

Thanks in advance guys! :)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this question... Could you maybe edit and give your expected result set?

Comment: The question is not clear and you should at least include the desired ouput so that we have a visual.

Comment: IF i understand what you want, you should have POST_ID 3, 4 and 5 as result but not the 2 since its from USER_ID 1.

Comment: Oh sorry guys. The expected result for user_id 1 would be: row 2,3,4,5 in TABLE 1

Comment: and the expected result for user_id 2 would be: row 1,3,4,5 in TABLE 1

Comment: Guys, it talks about user post. The post must be seen by user ONCE and it won't be displayed anymore. Get it? @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: Guys, it talks about user post. The post must be seen by user ONCE and it won't be displayed anymore. Get it? @Pachonk

Comment: Guys, it talks about user post. The post must be seen by user ONCE and it won't be displayed anymore. Get it? @olibiaz

Comment: Guys, it talks about user post. The post must be seen by user ONCE and it won't be displayed anymore. Got it.

Comment: @ctosdotcom I've come up with a much simpler approach using OUTER JOIN. Take a look at it in the Answers section

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an *anti join* pattern could achieve the specified result.

```
 SELECT t.post_id
      , t.user_id
      , t.description
   FROM `[Table 1]` t
   LEFT
   JOIN `[Table 2]` u
     ON u.post_id = t.post_id
    AND u.user_id = ?  
  WHERE u.post_id IS NULL
  ORDER BY t.post_id
```

The ? is the placeholder character for specifying a  userid.

This essentially says return *all* rows from Table 1 along with matching rows from Table 2, but (here's the trick) the WHERE clause says to *exclude* all rows that found a matching row in Table 2. Leaving only rows from Table 1 that don't have a match in Table 2.

The *anti join* takes a little bit of effort to get your brain wrapped around, but once you get it, it's an invaluable tool to keep handy  in the SQL toolbelt.

There are other query patterns that will return an equivalent result, such as a `NOT EXISTS (correlated subquery)` or the more common `NOT IN (subquery)`. (With the NOT IN, be careful that the subquery doesn't return any NULL values.)

**EDIT**

Removed the condition  `u.user_id = t.user_id`  from the join predicate. Looks like the `user_id` in `[Table 1]` is the "author" of the post. And has no relation to whether a user has "viewed" a post or not.

Comment: Edited query to remove condition `u.user_id = t.user_id` from the join condition. It looks like the `user_id` in the (unfortunately named) table `[Table 1]` is meant as the author of the post, and has no bearing on whether a post has been "viewed" by a user.

Answer (score 0):

Base on your sample data, because USER_ID 1 in TABLE 1 already existed in TABLE 2 with its respected POST_ID, it should return POST_ID 2,3,4,5.

Query:

```
SELECT t1.* FROM table2 t2
RIGHT OUTER JOIN table1 t1
ON t2.user_id = t1.user_id AND t2.post_id = t1.post_id
WHERE t2.user_id IS NULL
```

Final Result:

```
post_id     user_id     description
2           1           Sample post 2
3           2           Sample post 3
4           2           Sample post 4
5           3           Sample post 5
```

Is this what you are looking for?